# Spring Batch Flow Job - control number of jobs running simultaneously

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a complex long-running flow that I'm going to implement based on Spring Batch Flow Job.

My REST API will wait for the incoming request and then (based on each request) initiate a new job execution.

Right now I'm worried about the server resources because the number of incoming requests is a quite big and I'd like to control the number of jobs running simultaneously. Is there any way to tell Spring Batch to run simultaneously not more than the exact number of jobs(let's say 5) and put rest of the jobs into the queue in order to be executed later, when for example one of these previous 5 jobs will be finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a way to accomplish this in Spring Batch.  The reason for this is that the number of concurrent jobs is really an orchestration problem which Spring Batch specifically avoids solving (allowing you to integrate with whatever you want).

That being said, the ability to control what you're describing can be done in a relatively straight forward manor by implementing a work queue that stores the requests to run a job, and having a service picking up those requests at the other end.  The concurrency can be controlled easily with Spring Integration components to prevent the system from being overloaded (assuming you have a mechanism to handle the queue size in question).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please also point me how to control concurrency with Spring Integration?

Comment: Using an `ExecutorChannel`, you can configure a `TaskExecutor` where you'd control the concurrency.  For example, you could use a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` that has a finite number of threads.